# How to calculate Hamming distance for a Number slider puzzle

Tags: math, search, artificial-intelligence, heuristics, hamming-distance

How to calculate the [Hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) for the following puzzle:

[image]

As far as I understand I need to compare the following two sequences:

```
13-11-15-00-10-08-09-12-01-06-03-02-04-07-14-05
01-02-03-04-05-06-07-08-09-10-11-12-13-14-15-00
=
16
```

Or it's not that easy?

Comment: I get 25... but yes, it's that easy.

Comment: How come you get 25, there only 16 numbers in total

Comment: oh, sorry, I was comparing individual digits, as opposed to entire tiles.

Answer (score 2):

Right idea, wrong implementation.

The blank tile should not be treated as a tile numbered 00; the blank tile is not a tile at all, and should no be included in the computation.

(Do you see why?  The Hamming Distance is intended to be an admissible heuristic, and an admissible heuristic is one which is never pessimistic.  It must never estimate a cost worse than the actual cost.  But here, if only one tile is out of place, the Hamming-distance-including-blank will give an estimate of 2 while the actual cost is 1.)